# How to use { in place of opening tags and } in place of closing tags?

Tags: php

I am an `MVC` addict.

I have some `views` in plain PHP (not using any `Templating Engine` (TE) such as `Smarty` for getting good performance), but without `Smarty` my `views` are looking ugly and hard to code.

I'm wondering how can I make them look good (ie., human readable) without using any `TE`? At least I want to replace those `<?php` and `?>` for sure, or if you have any other better idea?

It's just a start of my web application so please guide me to any better alternative if you have any.

Thanks.

Comment: See 'short open tags' http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Why not use Smarty (or [Flexy](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Template_Flexy/))?

Comment: @Jared because it's PHP written in PHP. Do not multiply matters.

Comment: Well, I hope you're aware that Smarty compiles a template into plain PHP code at first use, so you may not be gaining much in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In templates I use the alternatives of PHP like:

```
<?php if (true): ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php foreach ($x as $y): ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 2):

There's no PHP variation or syntax that allows you to replace `<?php` and `?>` with `{` and `}`. If you want that, you'll need to use or write a custom parser for it, which means you're looking at a templating engine. No templating engine, no custom syntax.